# hadoop: can many map running parallelly in a single node share static data？when enble jvm reuse

Tags: java, hadoop, jvm

hadoop:when enble jvm reuse,several map or reduce tasks running parallelly in a single node share static data？

In another words: if I have a static String "xxx" in maper class, When enble jvm reuse,can 2 maps running parallelly in single node share the String "xxx"  or There is still 2 static String "xxx" in separate maps.

Why do I have the confusion? cause I see the below comments:

---

> Jobs can enable task JVMs to be reused by specifying the job
>   configuration mapred.job.reuse.jvm.num.tasks. If the value is 1 (the
>   default), then JVMs are not reused (i.e. 1 task per JVM). If it is -1,
>   there is no limit to the number of tasks a JVM can run (of the same
>   job). One can also specify some value greater than 1 using the api.
>   share|edit|flag answered Feb 2 '11 at 18:09 Joe Stein 749169 1
>          Thanks, one more question. Does those tasks also share some Class-loader, so all statics resources will be loaded only once? (Or
>   may it works like tomcat, in that way there are almost no reason to
>   share JVM...) –  yura Feb 4 '11 at 13:10 1
>          The JVM will be cleared after a task completes. This parameter only provides better runtime for jobs that are not "long-running"
>   since the jvm instantiation is very expensive. You could not share any
>   ressources over task instances. –  Thomas Jungblut Feb 4 '11 at 21:04

---

above comments reference from: [Is it possible to run several map task in one JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877691/is-it-possible-to-run-several-map-task-in-one-jvm)

Comment: I think my comment is really clear. You can't share data, the JVM's internal heap is wiped. You can't put stuff there and hope that other tasks pick it up.

Comment: Thanks for your comments,I think you have explained clearly why serial tasks cannot share static data.  But I still have a little confusion about parallel tasks.For example, Enble jvm reuse. When 2 maps running parallelly in single node,can the 2 map tasks share one JVM at that time? if the answer is true， Do you mean there are 2 heaps in the JVM？ Or other things happening stop the 2 maps sharing static data?

Comment: No, Hadoop does process isolation in order to help with fault tolerance. Isolating every map task is key in the restartability without invalidating too much of the other computation. So no: no tasks share the same JVM when they run in parallel, they are different processes.

Comment: So appreciate U,right now I got it

Comment: HI @Thomas Jungblut ，sorry for one more question,During the whole job running(I mean the the Job have been running for a while).Is there any way to add data in a memory which can be shared by all nodes's task. Just like distributed cache(but as I known，it only can be set in the beginning and it is consisted of local file)

Comment: Well you can read files when you're running your task, but you can't push stuff from the outside into the task's memory.

Comment: yep，I just thought of, If we deploy hbase and hadoop on the same cluster，We can use hbase as the"memory" shared by all nodes's task.